# CallKit "call failed screen" appears

Tags: ios, swift3, voip, sinch, callkit

When call is disconnected by receiver(after receiving the call) than call failed screen appears, I don't want this screen to be displayed. All my delegate methods are working. How can I make a successful call? What cause the call to be failed?

Comment: can u plz share the code of SINUIViewController

Answer (score 1):

To end the call, use **CXEndCallAction** and add the **CXTransaction** objects. Make sure you are using the correct **uuid**.

```
CXEndCallAction *action = [[CXEndCallAction alloc] initWithCallUUID:callUUID];
[self.callController requestTransaction:[CXTransaction ...Actions:@[action]] completion:completion];
```

Comment: I am using CXTransaction, One thing I observed that action.callUUID and action.uuid is different inside CXEndCallAction delegate. Which one should I use, I tried both but got no success.

Comment: callUUID is correct. Check the callUUID when the call initiated and while ending, both should be the same.

Comment: [self.provider reportCallWithUUID:callUUID endedAtDate:nil reason:CXCallEndedReasonRemoteEnded];
Check this as well.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same situation :P
But this is the solution:

```
- (void)provider:(CXProvider *)provider performEndCallAction:(CXEndCallAction *)action {
    /* Perform your action after ending the call */
    NSLog(@"performEndCallAction");
    [action fulfill];
}
```

When performEndCallAction gets called by CallKit, execute **[action fulfill]** in it :)